# jquery $().contents() giving me [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problems with my code and how to make it work I'm struggling with the jquery to get the text that is inside the `<a> </a>`. Currently, the code below just gives me back [object Object] could someone point me in the right direction.

```
<div id="conData" style="float:left; margin-left:10px;">
                <a id="ID" style="border-bottom:solid 1px grey;">24</a><br>
                <a id="UN" style="border-bottom:solid 1px grey;">joe b</a><br>
                <a id="RO" style="border-bottom:solid 1px grey;">email</a><br>
                <a id="CO" style="border-bottom:solid 1px grey;">6:00pm</a><br>
                <a id="DT" style="border-bottom:solid 1px grey;">UK</a><br>
                <a id="LC" style="border-bottom:solid 1px grey;">Jquery</a><br>

</div>

<button type="button" role="submit" id="ConfirmCourse">Confirm Course</button>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#ConfirmCourse', function() {
        var DataText = $('#conData').contents()
                                    .filter(function(){
                                         return this.nodeType === 3;})
                                   .wrap("<a></a>")
                                   .end();
                                   .filter( "br" )
                                   .remove();
        console.log(DataText);

</script>
```

edit: I've changed the code to `console.log(DataText);` that is giving the output below which i can't make heads or tails of.

```
[object Object]
   {
      [functions]: ,
      0: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         ATTRIBUTE_NODE: 2,
         attributes: null,
         CDATA_SECTION_NODE: 4,
         childNodes: { },
         COMMENT_NODE: 8,
         constructor: { },
         data: "
                ",
         DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE: 11,
         DOCUMENT_NODE: 9,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY: 16,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS: 8,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED: 1,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING: 4,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC: 32,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING: 2,
         DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE: 10,
         ELEMENT_NODE: 1,
         ENTITY_NODE: 6,
         ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE: 5,
         firstChild: null,
         lastChild: null,
         length: 5,
         localName: null,
         namespaceURI: null,
         nextSibling: null,
         nodeName: "#text",
         nodeType: 3,
         nodeValue: "
                ",
         NOTATION_NODE: 12,
         ownerDocument: { },
         parentNode: { },
         prefix: null,
         previousSibling: null,
         PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE: 7,
         TEXT_NODE: 3,
         textContent: "
                ",
         wholeText: "
                "
      },
      1: { },
      2: { },
      3: { },
      4: { },
      5: { },
      6: { },
      7: { },
      8: { },
      9: { },
      10: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         accessKey: "",
         ATTRIBUTE_NODE: 2,
         attributes: { },
         canHaveChildren: true,
         canHaveHTML: true,
         CDATA_SECTION_NODE: 4,
         charset: "",
         childElementCount: 0,
         childNodes: { },
         children: { },
         classList: { },
         className: "",
         clientHeight: 0,
         clientLeft: 0,
         clientTop: 0,
         clientWidth: 0,
         COMMENT_NODE: 8,
         constructor: { },
         contentEditable: "inherit",
         coords: "",
         currentStyle: { },
         dataset: { },
         dir: "",
         disabled: false,
         DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE: 11,
         DOCUMENT_NODE: 9,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY: 16,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS: 8,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED: 1,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING: 4,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC: 32,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING: 2,
         DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE: 10,
         draggable: true,
         ELEMENT_NODE: 1,
         ENTITY_NODE: 6,
         ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE: 5,
         firstChild: { },
         firstElementChild: null,
         hash: "",
         hidden: false,
         hideFocus: false,
         host: "",
         hostname: "",
         href: "",
         hreflang: "",
         id: "CO",
         innerHTML: " ArchGis",
         innerText: " ArchGis",
         isContentEditable: false,
         isDisabled: false,
         isMultiLine: true,
         isTextEdit: false,
         lang: "",
         language: "",
         lastChild: { },
         lastElementChild: null,
         localName: "a",
         Methods: "",
         mimeType: "",
         msContentZoomFactor: 1,
         msRegionOverflow: "undefined",
         name: "",
         nameProp: "",
         namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
         nextElementSibling: { },
         nextSibling: { },
         nodeName: "A",
         nodeType: 1,
         nodeValue: null,
         NOTATION_NODE: 12,
         offsetHeight: 22,
         offsetLeft: 157,
         offsetParent: { },
         offsetTop: 214,
         offsetWidth: 54,
         onabort: null,
         onactivate: null,
         onbeforeactivate: null,
         onbeforecopy: null,
         onbeforecut: null,
         onbeforedeactivate: null,
         onbeforepaste: null,
         onblur: null,
         oncanplay: null,
         oncanplaythrough: null,
         onchange: null,
         onclick: null,
         oncontextmenu: null,
         oncopy: null,
         oncuechange: null,
         oncut: null,
         ondblclick: null,
         ondeactivate: null,
         ondrag: null,
         ondragend: null,
         ondragenter: null,
         ondragleave: null,
         ondragover: null,
         ondragstart: null,
         ondrop: null,
         ondurationchange: null,
         onemptied: null,
         onended: null,
         onerror: null,
         onfocus: null,
         onfocusin: null,
         onfocusout: null,
         ongotpointercapture: null,
         onhelp: null,
         oninput: null,
         onkeydown: null,
         onkeypress: null,
         onkeyup: null,
         onload: null,
         onloadeddata: null,
         onloadedmetadata: null,
         onloadstart: null,
         onlostpointercapture: null,
         onmousedown: null,
         onmouseenter: null,
         onmouseleave: null,
         onmousemove: null,
         onmouseout: null,
         onmouseover: null,
         onmouseup: null,
         onmousewheel: null,
         onmscontentzoom: null,
         onmsgesturechange: null,
         onmsgesturedoubletap: null,
         onmsgestureend: null,
         onmsgesturehold: null,
         onmsgesturestart: null,
         onmsgesturetap: null,
         onmsgotpointercapture: null,
         onmsinertiastart: null,
         onmslostpointercapture: null,
         onmsmanipulationstatechanged: null,
         onmspointercancel: null,
         onmspointerdown: null,
         onmspointerenter: null,
         onmspointerleave: null,
         onmspointermove: null,
         onmspointerout: null,
         onmspointerover: null,
         onmspointerup: null,
         onpaste: null,
         onpause: null,
         onplay: null,
         onplaying: null,
         onpointercancel: null,
         onpointerdown: null,
         onpointerenter: null,
         onpointerleave: null,
         onpointermove: null,
         onpointerout: null,
         onpointerover: null,
         onpointerup: null,
         onprogress: null,
         onratechange: null,
         onreset: null,
         onscroll: null,
         onseeked: null,
         onseeking: null,
         onselect: null,
         onselectstart: null,
         onstalled: null,
         onsubmit: null,
         onsuspend: null,
         ontimeupdate: null,
         onvolumechange: null,
         onwaiting: null,
         outerHTML: "<a id="CO" style="border-bottom-color: grey; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;"> ArchGis</a>",
         outerText: " ArchGis",
         ownerDocument: { },
         parentElement: { },
         parentNode: { },
         parentTextEdit: { },
         pathname: "",
         port: "",
         prefix: null,
         previousElementSibling: { },
         previousSibling: { },
         PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE: 7,
         protocol: "",
         protocolLong: "",
         recordNumber: null,
         rel: "",
         rev: "",
         runtimeStyle: { },
         scrollHeight: 22,
         scrollLeft: 0,
         scrollTop: 0,
         scrollWidth: 54,
         search: "",
         shape: "rect",
         sourceIndex: 1187,
         spellcheck: true,
         style: { },
         tabIndex: 0,
         tagName: "A",
         target: "",
         text: " ArchGis",
         TEXT_NODE: 3,
         textContent: " ArchGis",
         title: "",
         type: "",
         uniqueID: "ms__id148014",
         uniqueNumber: 148014,
         urn: ""
      },
      11: { },
      12: { },
      13: { },
      14: { },
      15: { },
      16: { },
      17: { },
      18: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         ATTRIBUTE_NODE: 2,
         attributes: null,
         CDATA_SECTION_NODE: 4,
         childNodes: { },
         COMMENT_NODE: 8,
         constructor: { },
         data: "

                ",
         DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE: 11,
         DOCUMENT_NODE: 9,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY: 16,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS: 8,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED: 1,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING: 4,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC: 32,
         DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING: 2,
         DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE: 10,
         ELEMENT_NODE: 1,
         ENTITY_NODE: 6,
         ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE: 5,
         firstChild: null,
         lastChild: null,
         length: 10,
         localName: null,
         namespaceURI: null,
         nextSibling: null,
         nodeName: "#text",
         nodeType: 3,
         nodeValue: "

                ",
         NOTATION_NODE: 12,
         ownerDocument: { },
         parentNode: { },
         prefix: null,
         previousSibling: null,
         PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE: 7,
         TEXT_NODE: 3,
         textContent: "

                ",
         wholeText: "

                "
      },
      __proto__: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         jquery: "3.3.1",
         length: 0
      },
      jquery: "3.3.1",
      length: 19,
      prevObject: { }
   }
```

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you. The code you posted doesn't run.

Comment: That's because it's an object.  What do you expect?

Comment: Yes, please provide a minimal example. But at a glance it looks like "DataText" has the actual anchor element in it, and you want the innerText of that element. Dump DataText to the debugging console to see what the object actually is.

Comment: Try not alerting it.

Comment: Alert implicitly calls toString on the argument of the call. `toString.call({})` === `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: Also, in your case, `DataText` will be a jQuery collection containing the break tag that you removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the [docs of jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) `remove()` returns a jQuery object. This is what is causing the `[object Object]`.

Depending on what you want

Get the contents of anchors in an array:

```
var data = {};

$('#conData a').each(function () {
    data[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).text();
});
```

Will return the following

```
{
    ID: 24,
    UN: joe b
    RO: email
    ...
}
```

By the way: no need to use `filter` and `remove`, there are nu `<br />` elements in your content.

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful and worked great, how would i go about trying to convert this to an array? preferably `[[ID, 24], [UN, job b], [RO, email]]`

Comment: Thank you for your help again i've managed to convert the object to an array now by using `var data = '......' var result = Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
  return [String(key), data[key]];
});

console.log(result);`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your listener, you can just do :

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(text){
  console.log(text.innerHTML);
});
```

(You don't need jQuery)